# How to get checked items from checklistbox MVC Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkedlistbox

In a div, I have some `CheckBoxList` using `CheckBoxListFor` in `MVC Razor`. I'd like when I push a button to get all the values of all check boxes checked. How to do this?

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="" class="control-label">
                    Branch</label><br />
                @Html.CheckBoxListFor(m => m.SearchBranchSeq,MultiSelectList)Model.SearchBranches, new {@id="SearchBranches", @style = "overflow: auto; height: 100px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;" })

            </div>
```

And I tried like the following,

```
var SearchBranchSeq = [];
    $('input:checkbox').click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            SearchBranchSeq.push($(this).val());
      }
      else {
            var x = SearchBranchSeq.valueOf($(this).val());
            SearchBranchSeq.splice(x, 1);

      }
  });
```

It is working, but I cannot remove the value in `SearchBranchSeq` when I uncheck a check box from the `CheckBoxList`. Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) instead of [`valueOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_array.asp) on the array. As noted in the link `indexOf()` is defined in `Internet Explorer 9+` and the rest of the modern browsers.

```
// IE Old
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
// End IE Old - not needed if old IE is not supported

var x = SearchBranchSeq.indexOf($(this).val());
SearchBranchSeq.splice(x, 1);
```

Comment: It shows  this "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: Is this shown on the indexOf call or somewhere else. As far as I can see SearchBranchSeq is defined as an array before your click handler thus it contains definition of indexOf().

Comment: @MdAslam Also if you're using Internet Explorer < 9 then you will get this error.

Comment: It shows on the indexOf call and am using Internet Explorer < 9 also. Please help me to find the solution  @  Konstantin Dinev

Comment: Can you update the full code please? Because I am new to jquery and MVC Razor

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake only. And it is working perfectly, thank you so much  @ Konstantin Dinev

Comment: @MdAslam The definition of indexOf on the array.prototype should go at the beginning of your javascript.